# textView() method not being called in iMessage extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview, imessage-extension

My iMessage extension has a `UITextView` that needs to resign its `FirstResponder` when the user hits the return key. But I can't get the method used to trigger this to fire.

```
import UIKit
import Messages

class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var TextArea: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.TextArea.delegate = self
        self.KeyField.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if (text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use updated method for swift func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use swift updated `UITextViewDelegate` method.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You forget the  argument label `_`

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, 
   shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, 
    replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

Here in [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618630-textview)